# Android SQLite how to delete with limit

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, limit, delete-row

I want to delete only one row  from my database table *User*.

I tried [this](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_update_delete_limit), but I have no idea how to use `SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT`.

Here is my code:

```
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.openOrCreateDatabase("User", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        //sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO user (name, age) VALUES ('jihyo', 10)");

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM user WHERE name ='jihyo' LIMIT 1");
        Cursor c = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM user WHERE name = 'jihyo'", null);
        int nameIndex = c.getColumnIndex("name");
        int ageIndex = c.getColumnIndex("age");

        c.moveToFirst();
        do {
            Log.v("name", c.getString(nameIndex));
            Log.v("age", c.getString(ageIndex));
        } while (c.moveToNext());
```

Here is the error:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "LIMIT": syntax error
>   (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM user WHERE name ='jihyo'
>   LIMIT 1

Comment: use the unique ID of the data to be deleted to delete it from your table

Comment: You should always use an id to delete a person, it's safer and better

Comment: thx, but I want to delete with limit. lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
db.execSQL("Delete from user where user_id IN (Select user_id from user where name = 'jihyo' limit 1)");
```

[UPDATED] : the `=` doesn't work with the `LIMIT` operation so you need to make it like this :

```
Cursor c = db.execSQL("Select user_id from user where name = 'jihyo' limit 1");
        if (c.moveToFirst()){
            String id = c.getString(0);
            db.execSQL("Delete from user where user_id = "+id);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question.     I added two data like name = 'jihyo' age = 10, name = 'lihyo', age = 10 and 
 sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM user WHERE name IN (SELECT name FROM user WHERE name ='jihyo' LIMIT 1)"); but the result = it deleted all' It seemed limit wasn't work....

Comment: do you know why?

Comment: i updated my responce

Comment: thanks but did you use unique id?

Comment: yes it's the `id`

Answer (score 2):

You can't apply limit in delete query because **DELETE** **Clause** don't have **LIMIT**
so you can Select single record using **SELECT** query and apply **DELETE** on the bases
of selected query
eg.

```
DELETE FROM user WHERE id IN
 (SELECT id FROM user
 WHERE name = 'jihyo'
 LIMIT 1);
```

**Note**: you can use  '=' in place of  'IN'

Comment: Thanks for answering my question.     I added two data like name = 'jihyo' age = 10, name = 'lihyo', age = 10 and 
 sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM user WHERE name IN (SELECT name FROM user WHERE name ='jihyo' LIMIT 1)"); but the result is =  it deleted all data It seemed limit wasn't work....

Comment: do you know why???

Comment: You have applied condition on basis of name so it select query fetch one record containing name='jihyo' so delete query become 'Delete from user where name in('jihyo') so it will delete all users whose name is 'jihyo', you need to use other column name which is unique like id or some other column.

Comment: I get it thank you for answering my question have a good day!